# mysql 1054, unknown column, but I'm not specifying a column

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-statement

I have a basic customer table.
The columns are:

```
FirstName   LastName   Organization   PhoneNumber   City   State   Zip   ID
```

`ID` is an autoincremented value.

I want to insert a new record into the table so I issue this command:

```
INSERT INTO CustomerTable (FirstName, LastName, Organization, PhoneNumber, City, State, Zip) VALUES (John, Doe, None, 5555555555, Nowhere, NY, 12345);
```

However, when I issue this statement, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42s22): Unknown column 'John' in 'field list'
```

Why am I getting this error?  'John' is a value to go in a column, not an actual column itself.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake.  I don't have quotes around my strings.
I apologize for asking such a stupid question.

Comment: Put your string values in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the string values in quotes. Outside quotes those strings will be treated as column or variable names.

```
VALUES (John, Doe, None, 5555555555, Nowhere, NY, 12345)
```

Should be

```
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'None', 5555555555, 'Nowhere', 'NY', 12345)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This was a stupid question. I think I spent too much time in front of the computer screen, because this should have been obvious.

Answer (score 0):

John is a string. You need to put in ''.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `'` with all strings that you want to insert to database. In other case MySQL will think that you want to get value from column with given name (in this case `John`).